# Live audio feed in HTML 5

Tags: python, vlc, html5-audio, live-streaming, broadcasting

I am trying to make way to **broadcast live audio feeds** in **HTML 5** compatible means. I don't want many advance features and all. But however I am looking for everything to be Open source. Can any one shed light into this. I am comfortable with **python**. Is it possible with **python** to get the audio from mic and broadcast it in **HTML5** compatible format?

1. How can I make HTML 5 Play live feeds?
2. Is there any library or projects in python to broadcast audio?
3. Is there a way I can control VLC player from python for the purpose?

My Target audience will be very less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SHOUTcast](http://www.shoutcast.com/)/[Icecast](http://www.icecast.org/) and one of the many [encoders](http://www.icecast.org/ices.php) for those to encode and stream.

What you use on the player side is up to you, but you can do this with HTML5 or Flash.  It's just MP3 over HTTP.

Comment: but will html5 audio play mp3?

Comment: @esafwan, this depends on the browser.  Some do, some don't.  Flash is a far more universal way to accomplish this at the moment.  That may change in the future, but for now, that is the reality.  You can always stream in a different format if you wish, using the same encoders and server software.